# Modal and modeless forms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have the application in VB.NET where I have a main form (A) which opens another form (B) in modeless state. Then from the form A I want to open another form (C) as modal form.

Is there anyway to do anything on form B whilst the form C is still open?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. What have you tried? Could you show us your code?

Comment: You are asking for a very dangerous feature.  Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents/5183623#5183623) to understand why ShowDialog exists.  You otherwise get what you ask for by simply using Show() and disabling A by setting its Enabled property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be confusing for the user? B apparently needs A to be available but when you open C you break that functionality of B.

Nonetheless, you can probably use EnableWindow() to disable A instead of making C modal.

Comment: EnableWindow sounds reasonable. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to do anything on form B whilst the form C is still
>   open?

You also could switch to an MDI interface.